# query en mysql worbench

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo una problemática para realizar un query, el cual ya tengo como la mitad realizada pero no hace ciertas cosas ejemplo:
tengo dos tablas que están relacionadas.
tabla1_Evidencias y tabla2_catalogoEvidencias

entonces la tabla1_evidencias tiene

```
id|fk_catalogo_evidencia|ubicación|visita
1 |403                  |HTTP://1 |455
2 |398                  |HTTP://2 |14
3 |368                  |HTTP://3 |566
4 |380                  |HTTP://4 |555
```

tabla2_catalogoEvidencias

```
id  |Descripcion |etiqueta_Padre
403 |vitrina     |394 
394 |telcel      |null             
398 |arte        |394            
380 |capacitacion|null
368 |mesa        |null
```

la consulta deberia ser asi:

```
id_evidencia|descripcion evidencia padre|descripcion evidencia hija
1           |vitrina                    |telcel
2           |arte                       |telcel
3           |mesa                       |             
4           |capacitación               |
```

ES únicamente por poner un ejemplo yo he logrado hacer el query cuando exista una descripción padre y una hija pero no he logrado realizar para que muestre el caso cuando no tenga descripción hija

Espero pueda ayudarme y se los agradecería mucho
Saludos

---

```
select 

evi.id as id_evidencia,
CONCAT('https://api.sftracker.com', evi.path) AS Ubicacion,
tmp1.etiqueta_padre as padre_id,
tmp1.Nombre_padre as Etiqueta_padre,
evi.catalgo_evidence_type_id as etiqueta_Secundaria,
cetA.name as etiqueta_Secundaria
from
        catalgo_evidence_types cetA,
        (select distinct
            cetA.id as etiqueta_padre,
            cetA.name as Nombre_padre
        from
            catalgo_evidence_types cetA,
            catalgo_evidence_types cet
        where 
            cetA.id = cet.catalgo_evidence_type_id and

             cetA.is_active=1) tmp1,
             evidences evi
where 
    cetA.catalgo_evidence_type_id=tmp1.etiqueta_padre and
    evi.catalgo_evidence_type_id=cetA.id 

      group by 
        evi.id
    order by 
    evi.id,tmp1.Nombre_padre,cetA.name,cetA.is_active desc
```

Comment: y la consulta que has probado?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ahora, podes agregar tambien el resultado que obtuviste?

Answer (score 0):

En base a la estructura de ejemplo que pusiste podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
    select ev.id, cev.descripcion as 'descripcion_evidencia_padre', 
   (select descripcion from tabla2_catalogoEvidencias cev2 where cev2.id = cev.etiqueta_padre) 
    as 'descripcion_evidencia_hija' 
    from tabla1_evidencias ev 
    inner join tabla2_catalogoEvidencias cev on ev.fk_catalogo_evidencia = cev.id
    order by id asc
```

Espero y te sea de utilidad. Saludos.